# Zip only contents of directory using absolute path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, zip

A lot of solutions to zipping the contents of a folder, Excluding the folder, look like this:

```
zip -r contents.zip *
```

But I need to do this WITHOUT cd'ing into the directory, I want to use an absolute path.  But this command includes the parent directory:

```
zip -r everything.zip /some/path/to/folder/*
```

So how can I zip the contents ONLY using an absolute path?

Comment: What is the reason you do not want to cd to directory?

Comment: I guess I don't know If I can.  This is in a script being run on startup of an AWS EC2 server.  Does CD work in a bash script?

Comment: Of course :) You can use this question (and answer) as reference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-without-including-the-folder-itself/182036#182036

Comment: Ok, and doe that then return to the previous directory when done? Or no.. it stays there

Comment: at the end exec this: 
cd -
this will return you to the previous directory (before exec cd)